# Pattern for UI configuration

Tags: c++, design-patterns, winapi, user-interface

I have a Win32 C++ program that validates user input and updates the UI with status information and options.  Currently it is written like this:

```
void ShowError() {
    SetIcon(kError);
    SetMessageString("There was an error");
    HideButton(kButton1);
    HideButton(kButton2);
    ShowButton(kButton3);
}

void ShowSuccess() {
    SetIcon(kError);

    std::String statusText (GetStatusText());
    SetMessageString(statusText);

    HideButton(kButton1);
    HideButton(kButton2);
    ShowButton(kButton3);
}

// plus several more methods to update the UI using similar mechanisms
```

I do not likes this because it duplicates code and causes me to update several methods if something changes in the UI.

I am wondering if there is a design pattern or best practice to remove the duplication and make the functionality easier to understand and update.

I could consolidate the code inside a config function and pass in flags to enable/disable UI items, but I am not convinced this is the best approach.

Any suggestions and ideas?

Comment: Which UI toolkit?  I'm guessing the Microsoft one, but I can't tell from your code.

Comment: The code is fake.  I made it up to demonstrate the problem.  You are correct, the toolkit is Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Observer Pattern and State Pattern, when an validation happens to be successful or unsuccessful, attached buttons can change their state according to information provided in "notify" method. Please refer to GoF's book for further details, or just google them. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yours and Travis's replies match the direction I was heading in.  Thanx for the feedback guys!